# Error in Ubuntu 16.04 installation

Tags: 16.04

After the installation of the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the login to my account is not display anything. Only the classic wallpaper of the Ubuntu and one message error which is hidden after some seconds. Ι have the same problem and with the live CD.

Comment: I have a very similar problem. Same thing happened before when I tried to install the final Beta, install is successful, but the desktop environment does not load. When I try to run unity from the console, I get "Illegal instruction" segmentation fault

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, which gives you a console. Then log in, and then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This could help if the installation is stuck somewhere.

Comment: Nothing anomalous comes out from that. Everything is up-to-date and installed

Comment: I had this issue and this did NOT solve it for me. its a proprietary driver issue, apparently the video card driver gets corrupted. the main suggestions are to remove lightdm and reinstall it w/ dpkg-reconfigure lightdm, which fixes it for some people, but I've had to do a full wipe so I can go back to 15.10 until nvidia releases the binary for my card. I'm less than pleased, but i knew the risk involved.

Comment: This worked for me. I got the same problem described in the initial post. Also the message was blinking so apparently it was a problem with the graphic card drivers (I have GTX 970). After running the commands and reboot, now Ubuntu is working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I installed another graphical evriroment and specifically the 'lubuntu-desktop' and the problem solved.

Comment: So are you saying the default 'ubuntu-desktop' doesn't work and you now have to work with a different one?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: And what's the difference?

Comment: The GUI works without a problem. Before is displayed to me:  "sorry ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error" and i cannot use GUI.

Comment: But is it the same as if you had the standard 'ubuntu-desktop' ?

Comment: The other features of the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS edition are the same. The only thing which is changed is the graphical environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, now downloading another ubuntu based distro to see if that works. My system:

Skylake based M/B: GA-Z170X-UD5, i7 7600, GeForce GX 980 Ti

I noticed that the installer would sometimes only recognise the onboard graphics, so I had to replug the monitor cable, when I checked the error report it was clearly related to the graphics card. I guess it's some driver issue.