# Ubuntu stuck asking to remove installation medium on Hyper V install

Tags: system-installation, hyper-v

I'm trying to install 16.04 on a virtual machine on my Windows 10 laptop.  Everything goes fine with the install with the only variance from defaults is the usage of third party video drivers.  I click ok to reboot and it then tells me to remove the installation medium and press enter. It's a virtual machine install, how do I do that without removing my keyboard?

Comment: post exactly what error message you are getting.

Comment: There is no error message : )  It simple sits there.. on the screen it says "Please remove the installation medium then press enter:"

Comment: Thank you... but it's a Virtual Machine installation.  There is no DVD drive to eject... You just point to the ISO you download from Ubuntu's site and it does the rest.

Comment: Thanks again.. it wasn't quite the solution, but it did make me think of what might work. which was to switch the boot order, pushing "IDE" above "CD" on the settings "BIOS" section.  However, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Well for the problem you had, it was the solution. For my friend it worked like a charm. i don't understand what possibly could have gone wrong with your device.

Comment: Try unmounting/removing the Ubuntu installer ISO from the virtual machine, through your virtual machine software. That way the Ubuntu virtual machine will think the CD-ROM drive is empty.

Comment: Hi Nick... thank you for your thoughts.  I had just that idea.. When the "press ok to restart" dialog was up, I click "eject" from the "Media->DVD" menu, but when I clicked ok, the VM just hung.  If I click OK first, "eject" is grayed out.

Comment: Faced the same problem. I tried turning the VM off (as mentioned above by Sinscary) and started it after a bit and didn't see the "error" after that. I guess it fixes itself?

Comment: Please try this:
In the menu at the top of the screen, select:
Devices-> Optical Drives -> Remove disk from virtual drive -> force unmount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the latest update... I'm going to conclude that there is something amiss with 16.04.  Noting what user542100 commented: ( *Running on a Surface Pro 4. Ubuntu 14.04 works fine, but 16.04 just sits there after entering my password. Hyper-V manager shows this taking around 24% of the CPU, so something is going on.* )  I decided to download the 14.04 ISO and create a VM using that one.

Not only did it respond when I hit "Enter" when prompted, but when it restarted and I logged in, the desktop loaded (in the 16.04 build, "turning off" the VM and then starting it got me to the login screen, but once I logged in, the desktop never appeared and a crash report started flashing so quickly I couldn't read it.

The only problem that remains is that there is no network connection even after I entered the static IP information that is required for my network (a unique IP address, not that assigned to the physical NIC).  I will start a new thread for that one... also, going to full screen doesn't fill the screen, but, again, a new thread for that one.

So it appears to me, the ball is in Ubuntu's court.

Comment: This may help http://askubuntu.com/questions/759987/error-in-ubuntu-16-04-installation/759992#759992

Answer (score 14):

Taken from https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5078-hyper-v-create-linux-virtual-machine-windows-8-a.html:

> When Ubuntu reboots and stops telling Please remove installation media, click **Stop** to stop and close vm. This ejects the installation media
>
> [image]
>
> and now Restart vm, and you will be able to log in

Comment: Thanks!  I did try that... it booted to the login screen and then just hung after I logged in.  Eventually it starts flashing this error report, but it comes and goes so quick I can't read it.

Comment: I am trying this now..  Delete the VM then recreate.  Before starting it, I clicked on settings and pushed IDE up in the bios boot order above "CD".  That should solve the reboot problem, however, I'm thinking my "hang" problem has to do with the fact that I'm running on this machine which has high-end NVidia graphics: http://www.dell.com/us/p/alienware-17-r3/pd

Comment: "When Ubuntu reboots and stops telling Please remove installation media, click Stop to stop and close vm. "  this doesn't happen. It just sits there at "Please remove.."  and the attempt to solve the problem using the steps above did nothing.

Comment: Sorry... it didn't.  This:  "When Ubuntu reboots and stops telling Please remove installation media"... never happens.  It never "stops telling Please remove installation media".  The only thing I can do is to click stop... this isn't a solution.

Comment: Click stop than close hyper-v and restart again.

Comment: The problem I have with this is that it's not a "fix"... it's a workaround at best.  The "Fix" would be what I stated above... "Click Settings and move IDE above CD before starting the VM".  However, even that doesn't "Fix" the problem.  The OS should allow the user to click enter... if the medium wasn't removed, it should prompt the user "Run from installation medium or boot to hard disk", or something like that.  Ubuntu needs to address this.  I'll start another thread about the hang after reboot.

Comment: Update:  I left the VM window open and after about 20 minutes it actually rebooted.  (crazy timeout!  :) )  I saw some error message "intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package..." and waited another 5 minutes, then I saw a login screen.  I am sorry Nitesh, but "Click stop than close hyper-v and restart again" isn't a fix.  I think this forum should add a state: "mark as workaround".  I do appreciate the info and time... but I am a diehard user advocate and a "Fix" is something that makes things work as expected, a workaround is a way to make what should happen, happen, when it doesn't

Comment: Well i am glad atleast things "workedaround".

Comment: Thanks :)  I wish that was fully true.. after I login it just sits there, hung.  I think its the NVidia graphics card... do you agree?  Should I start a new thread?  Is there even a workaround for this?  ;)

Comment: Try to uncheck enable dynamic memory option

Comment: Fyi, I have the same problem on an actual laptop.

Answer (score 1):

After installing GnomeUbuntu 16.04 iso on Hyper-v went to the
Hyper-v/ Configuration Settings/Bios and moved IDE to 1st boot position.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i found that you just have to restart when you see that screen as it hangs on remove the media, even if i hit enter on my keyboard.  If I let it sit, eventually it runs through about a thousand lines of code on screen and errors out.  If I just hit reset then it restarts Ubuntu, and then brings me to the login screen.